# yolact++ in google colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run yolact++ on google colab, but without success. I'm following these steps:

```
!pip install cython
!pip install opencv-python pillow pycocotools matplotlib

!pip install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

!git clone https://github.com/dbolya/yolact.git

cd yolact
!mkdir weights
cd /content/yolact/external/DCNv2
!python setup.py build develop




x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DWITH_CUDA -I/content/yolact/external/DCNv2/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c /content/yolact/external/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/yolact/external/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_gcc\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libstdcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1011\" -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -DWITH_CUDA -I/content/yolact/external/DCNv2/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c /content/yolact/external/DCNv2/src/cuda/dcn_v2_cuda.cu -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/yolact/external/DCNv2/src/cuda/dcn_v2_cuda.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options '-fPIC' -DCUDA_HAS_FP16=1 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE=\"_gcc\" -DPYBIND11_STDLIB=\"_libstdcpp\" -DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI=\"_cxxabi1011\" -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=compute_75 -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -std=c++14
/content/yolact/external/DCNv2/src/cuda/dcn_v2_cuda.cu:7:10: fatal error: THC/THC.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <THC/THC.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc' failed with exit code 1
```

I don't know what else to do, I've tried everything. I've heard that it has to be a specific version of PyTorch, but the version doesn't exist on this site. Can anybody help me?

Comment: what is yolact? contact the author for any issues with that thing.